# Prove that critical damping converges fastest to equilibrium postion.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have just read this [PDF from ocw.mit.edu](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-ii-second-order-constant-coefficient-linear-equations/damped-harmonic-oscillators/MIT18_03SCF11_s13_2text.pdf).

**How to prove that critical damping gives the fastest return to the equilibrium position?**

I thought of proving that it converges faster than 1) the overdamped case & 2) the underdamped case. The overdamped case seems to be conceptually (with the two roots) clear but not how to prove it under all initial conditions. I don't know how to start with the underdamped case since the exponent is the same as in the critical case.

*How to prove that the assumption is true under **all initial conditions**?* I don't really know how to deal with the $(c_1+c_2t)$, especially the $t$, in the critical damping solution $$x=(c_1+c_2t)e^{-bt/2m}$$

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: The second answer is just plain wrong. I have two issues with Jeffrey Rolland's answer: 1. It is not clear why you are taking the limit at t tends to 0? Why are you comparing the values of the positions initially? After all they are not helpful in determining which falls to equilibrium position faster. 2. I noticed you used l'hopital's rule in differentiating. This is just not valid. You can only apply l'hopital's when it's in the case of 0/0 or infinity/infinity, which is not the case when you plug the value t = 0 in. Both of these issues are solved however if you instead take the limit as t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have simply the General solution of the differential equation; this is given in dependence of two constants $c_1,c_2$ and holds for all initial condition. For example the solution of the critical damped System is:

$(c_1+c_2t)e^{-bt/(2m)}$.

This holds for every initial conditions (requiring that the System is damped critically); any initial condition can be computed with this equation (one has only to adjust $c_1,c_2$). The $t$ can be understood as the time elapsed after the System Begins to oscillate. From the duration of the oscillation $T$ you can compute the ratios $\frac{x(t+T)}{x(t)}$ and look how small These ratios are to analyze how fast the System tends to Equilibrium.

The factor $(c_1+c_2t)$ arises as the most General solution of the critically damped oscillation equation.

Answer (score 1):

In the overdampened case, if we set $\lambda = \frac{b}{2m}$, $\omega_0 = \sqrt\frac{k}{m}$, and $a = \sqrt{\lambda^2 - \omega_0^2}$, then we have

$\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} \frac{(c_1 + c_2t)e^{-\lambda t}}{c_3e^{-(\lambda + a)t} + c_3e^{-(\lambda - a)t}}$

$= \lim\limits_{t \to \infty} \frac{(c_1 + c_2t)}{c_3e^{-at} + c_3e^{+at}}$

$\stackrel{\text{L'H}}{=} \lim\limits_{t \to \infty} \frac{c_2}{-ac_3e^{-at} + ac_3e^{+at}}$

$= 0$

so the critically-dampened case goes to the equilibrium position faster than any of the overdampened cases.

In the underdamped case, the mass actually reaches the equilibrium position in a finite amount of time, whereas in the overdampened case, the mass never quite reaches the equilibrium position in finite time.

Comment: What do you mean the mass never reaches equilibrium in finite amount of time? 
In the critically damped case, the general solution is $x(t)=c_1e^{rt} + c_2te^{rt}$ which has root $t=-\frac{c_1}{c_2}$ which is finite... But I definitely see that the graph is asymptotic... where am I going wrong?

Comment: If $-\frac{c_1}{c_2} < 0$, the mass never reaches the equilibrium position in a finite amount of (forward) time; I suppose this is what I meant, thinking about your comment ...? Certainly, after that amount of time, if $-\frac{c_1}{c_2} > 0$, the mass then proceeds back towards the equilibrium position, taking forever to do so, and is always closer to the equilibrium position than any of the overdampened cases, as well, I suppose.